# CSS alignment of drop down UL LI elements clipping off screen

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, alignment

I'm struggling with positioning on a pure css driven drop down menu: My left hand side options are working fine - and this code is based on code i found online - It does the job ok.

I'm trying to make my far right hand menu drop down and NOT be clipped off/screen - I believe i will need to use a combination of relative positioning and float right but have tried lots of combinations without the desired effect.

I've put my code into a JSfiddle to show a live example (in-fact it's pretty much identical to what i'm working on) - I have added a batch of css resets to the top to make jsfiddle behave properly (on my live site i'm using an external css reset).

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g7Lk7/1/

```
    .pit_toolbar_ul ul{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Any recommendations on how to get the far right drop down to align up against the right edge of the screen would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `right: 0` instead of `left: 0` for the right menu item. You can fix it adding this styles:

```
.pit_toolbar_ul li:hover ul.rightside {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
.pit_toolbar_ul li:hover ul.rightside li {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

and add `rightside` class to corresponding `ul`.

http://jsfiddle.net/g7Lk7/2/

Comment: Thanks so much - that works perfectly! I assumed i would have to set a float for the individual LI elements

Answer (score 0):

```
.pit_toolbar_ul li:hover ul.alignRight li
{
  position:relative;
  left:-30px;
}
```

Add this class to your style sheet this may help you. I have positioned your dropdown `li`.

Comment: Hi 3bu1 - This is a little bit too hacky for my liking, it's not really future proof - i've demonstrated this with a jsfiddle (if i add future menu items i will have to jiggle the -30px often): http://jsfiddle.net/zerzY/1/